# Shenandoah 2.0 elimination of forwarding pointer

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, shenandoah

In `Shenandoah 1.0` every single Object had an additional header - called `forwarding pointer`. Why was that needed and what is the reason that lead to its elimination in `Shenandoah 2.0`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, every single java Object has two headers: `klass` and `mark`. They have been there in each instance since forever (they can slightly change how a JVM handles [their flags internally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879157/usecompressedoops-usecompressedclasspointers-in-jdk-13-and-jdk-15) with recent JVMs, for example) and are used for various reasons (will go into detail about only one of them a bit further in the answer).

The need for a `forwarding pointer` is literally in [the second part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59044616/whats-the-mark-compact-algorithm-used-by-hotspot/59141137#59141137).  The `forwarding pointer` is needed in both `read barrier` and `write barrier` in `Shenandoah 1.0` (though the *read* could skip the barrier for some field types - will not go into detail). In very simple words it simplifies *concurrent copy* very much. As said in that answer, it allows to atomically switch the `forwarding pointer` to the new copy of the Object and then *concurrently* update all references to point to that new Object.

Things have changed a bit in `Shenandoah 2.0` where the "to-space invariant" is in place : meaning all the writes and reads are done via the `to-space`.This means one interesting thing : once the `to-space` copy is established, the `from-copy` is never used. Imagine a situation like this:

```
    refA            refB
      |               |
fwdPointer1 ---- fwdPointer2        
                      |
  ---------       ---------  
  | i = 0 |       | i = 0 | 
  | j = 0 |       | j = 0 | 
  ---------       ---------
```

In `Shenandoah 1.0` there were cases when *reading* via the `refA` could bypass the barrier (not use it at all) and *still* read via the `from-copy`. This was allowed for `final` fields, for example (via a special flag). This means that even if `to-space` copy already existed and there were already references to it, there could still be *reads* (via `refA`) that would go to the `from-space` copy. In `Shenandoah 2.0` this is prohibited.

This information was used in a rather interesting way. Every object in Java is aligned to 64 bits - meaning the last 3 bits are *always* zero. So, they dropped the `forwarding pointer` and said that : if the last two bits of the `mark` word are `11` (this is allowed since no else uses it in this manner) -> this is a `forwarding pointer`, otherwise the `to-space` copy does yet exists and this is a plain header. You can [see it in action right here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/oops/markWord.hpp#l219) and you can trace the masking [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/oops/markWord.hpp#l141) and [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/oops/markWord.hpp#l160).

It used to look like this:

```
| -------------------|
| forwarding Pointer |
| -------------------|

| -------------------|
|        mark        |
| -------------------|

| -------------------|
|        class       |
| -------------------|
```

And has transformed to:

```
| -------------------|
| mark or forwarding |     // depending on the last two bits
| -------------------|

| -------------------|
|        class       |
| -------------------|
```

So here is a possible scenario (I'll skip `class header` for simplicity):

```
  refA, refB            
       |               
      mark   (last two bits are 00)   
       |              
    ---------   
    | i = 0 |      
    | j = 0 |      
    ---------
```

`GC` kicks in. The object referenced by `refA/refB` is alive, thus must be evacuated (it is said to be in the "collection set"). First a copy is created and atomically `mark` is made to reference that copy (also the last two bits are marked as `11` to now make it a `forwardee` and not a `mark word`):

```
  refA, refB            
       |               
     mark (11) ------  mark (00)   
                           |
    ---------          ---------
    | i = 0 |          | i = 0 |
    | j = 0 |          | j = 0 |
    ---------          ---------
```

Now one of the `mark word`s has a bit pattern (ends in `11`) that indicates that it is a *forwardee* and not a mark word anymore.

```
       refA              refB            
         |                 |               
     mark (11) ------  mark (00)   
                           |
    ---------          ---------
    | i = 0 |          | i = 0 |
    | j = 0 |          | j = 0 |
    ---------          ---------
```

`refB` can move concurrently, so then `refA`, ultimately there are not references to the `from-space` object and it is garbage. This is how `mark word` acts as a `forwarding pointer`, if needed.