# Space required to keep largest integer array in memory

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

I am reviewing an algorithm and it keeps an array of integers, the size of input is dynamic. So according to my calculations it can take as much as

```
  integer MAX_VALUE  * int size  = ?   
      2^31 integers  * 4 bytes   = ?
2147483648 integers  * 4 bytes   = 8 Gigabytes
```

Is this calculation correct ? would the JVM use this much contiguous space to store the int array or are there other things that one needs to consider ?

Comment: Yes the basic calculation is correct, but the jvm must also be configured for it, and the underlying machine needs enough ram to support that configuration. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382531/why-i-cant-create-an-array-with-large-size.

Comment: oh, great to know @Gene thanks

Comment: yes the concern is the RAM of the machines that runs this software

Comment: Is it an `int[]` or `Integer[]`?

Comment: it is an int[] @Eugene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theoretical size of the array would be :

- numberOfElementsInTheArray * 4 bytes
- 12 bytes of headers (`int[]` is an Object). Actually the size of headers depends on the flags you used and [on the JVM version you are running this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879157/usecompressedoops-usecompressedclasspointers-in-jdk-13-and-jdk-15)
- 4 bytes to keep the `length` of the array
- padding.

For example: (I am going to use [JOL for this](https://github.com/openjdk/jol)):

```
    int [] x = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        x[i] = 9999;
    }
    System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance((Object)x).toPrintable());
```

will output:

```
 [I@7a81197dd object externals:
      ADDRESS       SIZE TYPE PATH                           VALUE
    70fe45268         56 [I                                  [9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999, 9999]
```

So it has `56 bytes`:

- 40 for the values themselves (10 ints * 4 bytes)
- 12 for headers
- 4 for length
- 0 for padding

---

If you change this array to `Integer`, things change dramatically. `Integer` is an Object so you will store a reference inside the array (which could be `4` or `8` bytes, depending on `UseCompressedOops` flag), plus each of the `Integer` instances will require 2 headers (each `Integer` is an Object).

```
    Integer[] y = new Integer[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;++i){
        y[i] = 9999;
    }

    System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance((Object)y).toFootprint());
```

which will show:

```
   [Ljava.lang.Integer;@369f73a2d footprint:
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
     1        56        56   [Ljava.lang.Integer;
    10        16       160   java.lang.Integer
    11                 216   (total)
```

A total of `216 bytes`:

- 4 bytes for each reference (I have `UseCompressedOop` turned on), 40 bytes total
- 12 bytes headers of the array
- 4 bytes length of the array
- 0 bytes padding

Each reference from that array points to an `Integer`, each of those Objects will have `16 bytes`:

- 4 bytes for the inner `int` they hold
- 12 bytes headers
- 0 bytes padding

Comment: this makes it so clear why we need to do tasks with primitives as much as possible.  great details!

Comment: @mcvkr just notice that there is a JEP in java where Objects might drop headers in special cases, but it seems there is a long way there

Comment: can public see the JEP or does it need a openJDK account?

Comment: @mcvkr project ValHalla. you can accept the answer, btw.

Comment: Thanks again, looks like, the specific JEP for this is :  http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169 in scope of the ValHalla project

Answer (score 1):

## Array size maximum < `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

No, your maximum is incorrect.

The limit on number of elements in an array in Java is a little bit less than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) (2,147,483,647), depending on the version of Java, the host OS, and how Java was compiled. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31388054/642706) by Ivan Mamontov on the Question, [*Why I can't create an array with large size?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31382531/642706).

## Yes, biggest array of `int` ≈ 8 gigs

So the size of a maximum array of `int` will be roughly `( Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8L ) * 32L` bits which is 68,719,476,448 bits which is 8,589,934,556 octets.

So yes, around 8 gigs of memory. And remember: this is *contiguous* memory for an array. So:

- There may be significant work on the part of the [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) and host OS to produce such an array depending how fragmented is memory at that moment during runtime.
- If the host hardware does not have sufficient real memory, you'll be lapsing into virtual memory where the resulting paging may lead to terrible performance.

Always make real-world tests if you really are pushing these limits in your work. And you may want to consider alternative implementations of Java designed for very large memory, such as *Zing* by Azul Systems.

Comment: and what if it is an `Integer` array @Basil or a List of Integers? Because one can easily switch to those from an `int` array

Comment: @mcvkr Objects take up more room than primitives, and execute a bit slower than primitives. So when minimizing memory or execution time is paramount, use primitive `int` and arrays. Otherwise, for more convenience, use class `Integer` and collections such as `List` and `Set`.

Comment: FYI: Work is underway, led by Oracle, to largely eliminate the difference between primitives and objects — but won’t arrive soon.

Comment: [a lot more...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65568047/1059372)