# Why does primitive data type consume much memory than reference data type for this scenario in Java?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, primitive-types

I tried to check the memory consumption of a program. During the check, I have noticed some interesting things.

I created a Load class, which contains some fields.

```
class Load {
    String name;
    String title;
    long id;
}
```

I created 500000 Load objects and add them to an ArrayList. I have found, it took around `18 MB` of memory.

Then, I modified the Load class and use `reference` type Long.

```
class Load {
    String name;
    String title;
    Long id;
}
```

Again created 500000 Load objects and add them to ArrayList. Interestingly this time it took less memory than the previous one. It way 14 MB.

Run test changing os and JVM version. Found the following results.

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
JDK: 11 64bit
 
Object Created  | Load Object         | Memory | Load Object         | Memory  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. 500000       | With primitive long | 18 MB  | With reference Long | 14 MB
2. 900000       |                     | 32 MB  |                     | 26 MB
3. 1500000      |                     | 53 MB  |                     | 41 MB

OS: macOS Big Sur 64 bit
JDK: 8 64bit
 
Object Created  | Load Object         | Memory | Load Object         | Memory  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. 500000       | With primitive long | 18 MB  | With reference Long | 14 MB
2. 900000       |                     | 32 MB  |                     | 26 MB
3. 1500000      |                     | 53 MB  |                     | 41 MB
```

Surprisingly, in all of these test runs, Object contains primitive types long consume more memory than Object contains reference Long.

### My question is, why primitive type takes more memory in this scenario?

Memory Tester Code:

```
public class MemoryChecker {

    private static final long MEGABYTE = 1024L * 1024L;

    public static long bytesToMegabytes(long bytes) {
        return bytes / MEGABYTE;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Load> list = new ArrayList<Load>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 500000
                ; i++) {
            list.add(new Load("Jim", "Knopf", 11L));
        }
        // Get the Java runtime
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        // Run the garbage collector
        runtime.gc();
        // Calculate the used memory
        long memory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
        System.out.println("Used memory is megabytes: " + bytesToMegabytes(memory));
    }
}
```

Complete code [git repo](https://github.com/khabib97/StackOverflow-Responses/tree/main/JVM-Memory-Management).

Comment: because this _isn't_ the way you measure memory

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553061/space-required-to-keep-largest-integer-array-in-memory/65568047#65568047) + easy for you to set-up your own examples...

Comment: 500000 `long` should be 4 MB, `Long` should be 8 MB following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258120/what-is-the-memory-consumption-of-an-object-in-java/258150#258150 - before some optimizations take place. By the way: what happens if you test this repeatedly, are the memory results the same?

Comment: @Eugene, Thanks for the link.

Comment: `Runtime.gc()` doesn't actually guarantee to run a garbage collection immediately.

Comment: @luk2302 repeatedly test, gives same result.

Comment: Is it a 64-bit JVM with 8 bytes per Object reference?

Comment: @Joop Eggen, yes it is 64 bit jvm, and 8 bytes per object reference. Can you write more details?

Comment: Do you fill `id` field? With heaps less than 32GB, an object reference is 4 bytes even on a 64-bit JVM. Indeed smaller than 8 bytes `long`.

Comment: @apangin, yes tested it both fill and without fill, but the result was almost similar for smaller values.

Comment: Then post the *full* code with filling `id`. Your current example does not even compile.

Comment: @apangin, this code is not the full version. `does not even compile` reason, the constructor is missing here, sorry for this. If you don't mind can check the git repo: https://github.com/khabib97/StackOverflow-Responses/tree/main/JVM-Memory-Management

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib sorry,  I wanted to check it was not 32 bit (or 64 bits) with 4 byte object addresses. Together with a `this`  that then would be exactly 4MB. See [Compressed OOPs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 32 Bit JVMs, but also for 64 Bit JVMs with the [*CompressedOOPs*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) feature (which is supported by the HotSpot JVM and on by default), a reference consumes only 4 bytes, compared to the 8 bytes of a `long`.

Even when you initialize the reference with an actual object, it may consume less memory when the object is *shared*. This applies to [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) of constants:

> If the value p being boxed is the result of evaluating a constant expression ([§15.29](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29)) of type `boolean`, `byte`, `char`, `short`, `int`, or `long`, and the result is `true`, `false`, a character in the range `'\u0000'` to `'\u007f'` inclusive, or an integer in the range `-128` to `127` inclusive, then let `a` and `b` be the results of any two boxing conversions of `p`. It is always the case that `a == b`.

but also to all operations ending up at [`Long.valueOf(long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(long)) in general.

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

Of course, if you create a lot of unshared `Long` objects, they will consume far more memory than the primitive `long`. If you use a lot of distinct values, even a potential sharing of them wouldn’t help.

Answer (score 3):

- The largest `primitive` can hold `8 bytes`.
- every Object has *at least* `12 bytes` (with default 64 bit VMs and relatively small heap) of headers. Automatically making it bigger than a primitive.

There is a single good library that I am aware of that does correctly, called `jol`. [here is a related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65553061/space-required-to-keep-largest-integer-array-in-memory/65568047#65568047) question.

It is rather easy to get `jol` set-up and [run the samples](https://github.com/openjdk/jol/tree/master/jol-samples) to understand the *actual* numbers you are interested in.

Comment: Can you explain this scenario:  https://www.baeldung.com/java-primitives-vs-objects#2-memory-footprint-for-arrays ?

Comment: @Md.KawserHabib how can I answer that question if I have no idea how they measured? and as soon as they say `boolean - 1 bit`, is where that article inspires zero trust to me.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions. I will try jol. :)

Comment: @Eugene I became skeptical when I read “baeldung.com” already. To be fair, after the “boolean – 1 bit” there’s the sentence “*In practice, these values can vary depending on the Virtual Machine implementation.*” to reconcile, but then, it proceeds with “*In Oracle's VM, the boolean type, for example, is mapped to int values 0 and 1, so it takes 32 bits*” linking to the formal specification rather than an implementation documentation, mixing up as many things as one can in just one sentence.

Comment: @Holger indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

As 'Long id' is not initialized so it only occupied 4/8 bytes (depends on VM and OS) where a 'long id' initialized with 0L by default which occupied 8 bytes.

Comment: These things are not that simple. Java uses optimization here. Read this answer, it is interesting https://stackoverflow.com/a/66365483/9457633