# OpenJDK 19 and compressed pointers

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, java-19

I have a hard time understanding how compressed pointers works in Java 19, help is appreciated.

In Java 11 the reference size is 4 for heaps below 32GiB (compressed pointers) and 8 for a larger heap. In Java 19 they seem to take 4 bytes even for larger heaps (how?).

Details:

Java versions: OpenJDK Java 11.0.12 and OpenJDK Java 19.0.1

Command lines:

> -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC  -Xlog:gc -Xlog:gc+heap+coops -Xms41g -Xmx41g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

> -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseEpsilonGC  -Xlog:gc -Xlog:gc+heap+coops -Xms31g -Xmx31g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch

Code: https://github.com/cornelcreanga/fun/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ccreanga/various/RandomAllocate.java - the code is taken from https://shipilev.net/jvm/anatomy-quarks/23-compressed-references/

Run this code with both Java 11 and 19 and you can see that the memory size is lower in Java 19 than in Java 11 for a heap > 32 GiB. For a smaller heap the size is almost identical.

Comment: basically a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879157/usecompressedoops-usecompressedclasspointers-in-jdk-13-and-jdk-15)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking at the layout of a `byte[]` array and an instance of `java.lang.Object`. Neither of them contains a reference to an object inside the heap.

The difference you are seeing, is in the size of the *class pointer* which is not pointing to a location inside the heap memory. But for historical reasons, the option `-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers` was bound to the presence of the `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` option. So when the heap size disallowed compressed object pointers, the compressed class pointers were disabled as a side effect.

[JDK-8241825, Make compressed oops and compressed class pointers independent](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8241825) addresses this and has been solved with JDK 15.

So when I change your program to

```java
System.out.println(ClassLayout.parseInstance(new Object[3]).toPrintable());
```

and run it with a 41GB heap, I get

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; object internals:
OFF  SZ               TYPE DESCRIPTION               VALUE
  0   8                    (object header: mark)     0x0000000000000001 (non-biasable; age: 0)
  8   8                    (object header: class)    0x000001f54bec41e0
 16   4                    (array length)            3
 20   4                    (alignment/padding gap)
 24  24   java.lang.Object Object;.<elements>        N/A
Instance size: 48 bytes
Space losses: 4 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

prior to JDK 15 and

```
[Ljava.lang.Object; object internals:
OFF  SZ               TYPE DESCRIPTION               VALUE
  0   8                    (object header: mark)     0x0000000000000001 (non-biasable; age: 0)
  8   4                    (object header: class)    0x000020fc
 12   4                    (array length)            3
 16  24   java.lang.Object Object;.<elements>        N/A
Instance size: 40 bytes
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

with JDK 15 or newer.

The difference is clearly caused by the class pointer and the padding, but the three object references require 24 bytes in each JVM version.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will also add a link that might be usefull for someone in future https://stuefe.de/posts/metaspace/what-is-compressed-class-space/